# Add attribute to yii2 checkboxlist container div

Tags: php, yii2

I'm trying to use custom template for yii2 checkboxlist I'm using the code:

```
<?=
 $form->field($model, 'fruit_ids')->checkboxList($fruits, [
        'item' => function($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) {
            return "<label class='col-md-4'><input type='checkbox' {$checked} name='{$name}' value='{$value}'>{$label}</label>";
        }
]);
?>
```

Which output:

```
<div id="testform-fruit_ids">
    <label class="col-md-4"><input type="checkbox" name="TestForm[fruit_ids][]" value="0">Apple</label>
    <label class="col-md-4"><input type="checkbox" name="TestForm[fruit_ids][]" value="1">Banana</label>
    <label class="col-md-4"><input type="checkbox" name="TestForm[fruit_ids][]" value="2">Orange</label>
    <label class="col-md-4"><input type="checkbox" name="TestForm[fruit_ids][]" value="3">Pear</label>
    <label class="col-md-4"><input type="checkbox" name="TestForm[fruit_ids][]" value="4">Pineapple</label>
</div>
```

But I want to add attribute **`class="btn-checkbox options`"** and **`data-toggle="button"`** to **`<div id="testform-fruit_ids">`** wrapper div element, i.e. I want the output like:

```
<div id="testform-fruit_ids" class="btn-checkbox options" data-toggle="button">
    <label class="col-md-4"><input type="checkbox" name="TestForm[fruit_ids][]" value="0">Apple</label>
    <label class="col-md-4"><input type="checkbox" name="TestForm[fruit_ids][]" value="1">Banana</label>
    <label class="col-md-4"><input type="checkbox" name="TestForm[fruit_ids][]" value="2">Orange</label>
    <label class="col-md-4"><input type="checkbox" name="TestForm[fruit_ids][]" value="3">Pear</label>
    <label class="col-md-4"><input type="checkbox" name="TestForm[fruit_ids][]" value="4">Pineapple</label>
</div>
```

Please tell me the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'fruit_ids')->checkboxList($fruits, [
        'item' => function($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) {
            return "<label class='col-md-4'><input type='checkbox' {$checked} name='{$name}' value='{$value}'>{$label}</label>";
        },
        'class' => 'btn-checkbox options',
        'data-toggle' => 'button'
   ]); ?>
```

Comment: Thank. How many attribute I can add like this and how Yii determine item content should placed inside div and class should placed inside div start tag.

Comment: Only limit there is PHP and HTML limitation so it shouldn't be a problem with reasonable number of attributes. As for the Yii look at the code starting from [checkboxList() method](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.9/framework/widgets/ActiveField.php#L622)

Answer (score 1):

update your code like below

```
<?=
 $form->field($model, 'fruit_ids')->checkboxList($fruits, ['class'=>"btn-checkbox options",'data-toggle'=>"button",
        'item' => function($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) {
            return "<label class='col-md-4'><input type='checkbox' {$checked} name='{$name}' value='{$value}'>{$label}</label>";
        }
]);
?>
```

add your class `'class'=>"btn-checkbox options"` and `'data-toggle'=>"button"` into the array.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following solution to add attribute `class="btn-checkbox options"` and `data-toggle="button"` to the `<div id="testform-fruit_ids">` wrapper `div` element:

```
$form->field($model, 'oFacilities')->checkboxList(Facility::forWidget(),[
    'item' => function($index, $label, $name, $checked, $value) {
        $checked = $checked ? 'checked' : '';
        return "<label class='checkbox col-md-4' style='font-weight: normal;'><input type='checkbox' {$checked} name='{$name}' value='{$value}'>{$label}</label>";
    }
])
```